# Run time error : 438 using Macro

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, runtime-error

I am using a code to extract the outlook email details in to an Excel using VBA.

While running the macro it throws a error :

> Run time error:438 -- Object does not support this property or method

and below is the line where it throws the error while clicking on debug.

```
wks.Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
```

Comment: Is the item that is referenced by `iRow` a `MailItem`?  An inbox can have more types of items than simply email.

Comment: Hi Mascaro,Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer
   For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count
        oRow = iRow + 1
        wks.Cells(oRow, 1).Select
        wks.Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
        wks.Cells(oRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
        wks.Cells(oRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
        wks.Cells(oRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
        wks.Cells(oRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
        wks.Cells(oRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
    Next iRow
    MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"

Comment: Hi Mascaro,to give better clarity on my query have attached the code used in this macro.

Comment: Do not put code in comments.  Please edit your question to include. Also, having the code does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do not use multiple dot notation, especially in a loop. Cache the Items collection before entering the loop. Secondly, chances are you have an item other than MailItem, e.g. ReportItem or MeetingItem object - check the Class property first. It will be olMail (=46) for the MailItem objects:

```
set items = Folder.Items
...
for iRow = 1 to item.Count
  set item = items.Item(iRow)
  if item.Class = 46 Then 'olMail
    wks.Cells(oRow, 1) = item.SenderName
  End If
neext
```